# how to generate @Html.Partial with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to asp mvc
I'm trying to include a custom component with this line of code:

```
 @Html.Partial("Components/FlightPlanSelect", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", "Flightplan" }, { "name", "FlightPlanId" } })
```

if I put this in my html, it will work fine. the problem is I want to add this dynamically with jquery. I don't know how to do that.

I'd appreciate you help

Comment: Use ajax to call a server method that returns the partial and update the DOM. Or put in inside a hidden element and use jquery to display it.

Comment: can you put some code for me? I'm not familiar with the way you said

Comment: Which option (ajax?)

Comment: hidden element doesn't do the trick for me. because it's a lot of html and jquery in the partial

Comment: _jquery in the partial_? Scripts should **never** be in partials, only the main view or its layout.

Comment: I have a section in my page which uses a custom component repeatedly. I can't just put its codes inside my page. if I can't use Partial then what is the other solution?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. All scripts should be in the main view (and if you think they need to be in a partial then your not understanding how to write a script). No one can give an answer until you give some more context. How do you want to trigger adding the partial (a button click?). What is the partial your trying to add? Does it have any editable controls?